# Peeling vegetables on Pesach

Tags: minhag, passover, chabad, vegetables, stringency-chumrah

It is a minhag in Chabad to only eat vegetables that you can peel on Pesach. There is a possibility that either the wax coating on certain vegetables contains chometz or that certain processing of the vegetables contains chometz. Without discussing the validity of this minhag, the question is do other groups outside of Chabad follow this chumra?

Comment: slight nitpick and clarification. A Chabad custom is one the Rebbeim told us to do. If the Rebbeim did not instruct us to act in a certain way, it is not a Chabad custom. If there are Chabad Chassidim that do it, it is a custom that some Chabadnik's follow, but not a Chabad custom. Harav Shusterman stresses this point in his shiurim, especially the ones connected to Pesach.

Comment: @Menachem it seems like that would, by definition, need to be sourced in Chabad Rebbeim. :)

Comment: @Menachem While you are correct that it is not official Chabad minhagim since it is not published in Sefer HaMinhagim. It seems to me that the majority of Chabad Chassidim follow this. I have heard R' Shusterman's shuir on Pesach and have not heard him say this. Is this shiur recorded?

Comment: @mochinrechavim: I heard the shiur last year, and I don't remember which one of his shiurim it was. There are several pesach shiurim on chabad.org, it may have been one of those.

Comment: @Menachem My wife is going to his Pesach Shuir tonight. I will let you know what he says. R' Schusterman is one of the most misquoted Rabbi's I know.

Comment: @Menachem, I just asked my friendly neighborhood Kapuster about this minhag.  He said it was not a Chabad minhag and was started as a chumra by the "Lubavitcher rebbe".  I did not ask which one, but was evident from his lack of description that it was either the previous or, earliest, the 6th.

Comment: @YDK: Does he have a source?

Comment: @Menachem, my buddy the Kapuster is a Chabadnick and says that there was never such a minhag among Kapusters.  Do you know anyone from Chabad besides Lubavitchers that have this minhag?  Do you know anyone from Chabad besides Lubavitchers? :)

Comment: @YDK: Sorry for not being more clear. I was asking if he has a source that this minhag was started by _the "Lubavitcher rebbe"_. See my first comment.

Comment: You mean as opposed to another posek from Lubavitch and then it just spread?  I'll ask him next chance.

Comment: R' Shusterman said that it is not an official minhag in Chabad because a minhag is only official when the Rebbe makes it a minhag. However the Rebbe spoke about it and it is something that was brought over from Russia and is not in most Chabad homes something that must be done.

Comment: @mochinrechavim: you wrote _and is not in most Chabad homes something that must be done._ did you mean _and is in most Chabad homes something that must be done._?

Comment: @Menachem, My buddy says he has no specific source that this minhag came from the Lubavitcher rebbe except that is what he heard from his chasidim.  He said the minhag did not exist when he was growing up.  He first heard it in the 70s.  He was told that someone had told the rebbe that produce was being coated to give it a shine, and since the rebbe was unsure of its makeup, he said that better it shouldn't be eaten.

Comment: all fruit and vegetables are by nature covered by different types of yeast strains one can make hard cider without adding yeast,sauerkraut is fermented cabbage using its own yeast strain, so by eating non peeled fruit and veg during pesach its possible to induce fermentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a practice unique to Chabad, and did not even originate with Chabad.

The Nitei Gavriel ([Pesach vol 2, chapter 39, paragraph 14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&st=&pgnum=211)) mentions this custom, saying that "Many are stringent on Pesach to only eat peeled vegetables".

In the footnote he references the [Chayei Adam 127:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49395&pgnum=312) ([not a Chabad source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Danzig)) and [Orchot Chayim Lifshitz (notes to Orach Chayim 447)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7772&pgnum=59) (I don't know enough about him to know his Chassidic affiliations).

Both those sources say that if we are worried that dried fruits may have some flour/chometz on them, we should also worry about peels.

If we are certain that there is no way chometz came in contact with them, [we may eat the dried fruit](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&st=&pgnum=207). If we're learning that one should peel fruits and vegetables from dried fruits, it would stand to reason that if one is certain chometz did not come in contact with the fruit or vegetable (e.g. they are home grown, and the grower was careful not to bring chometz near the fruit), one need not peel them.

Comment: It seems the Orchot Chaim Lifshitz was published in Germany 14 years after the death of the Ba'al HaTanya. I'd say it's highly unlikely he was a chabadnik.

Comment: I would put the emphasis on the Nitai Gavriel.  The sources that he brings- the Chaye Adam and the Orchos Chaim - may be the basis for the minhag, but they only mention specific circumstances where there is a known chashash.  They do not speak of a blanket chumra to eat only peeled produce.

Comment: @YDK: as with dried fruit (paragraph 2 here - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&st=&pgnum=207 - although see footnote 3 ) one does not have to be stringent if he is certain that no chometz came in contact with the item.

Comment: @Menachem, accordingly, there is no minhag of restricting produce to items which are peeled/shelled.  The minhag should only apply to produce which is , for example, waxed or coated.

Comment: @YDK: There is a minhag brought in paragraph 17 (http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&st=&pgnum=212), that some don't buy fruits and vegetables from a non-jew during pesach, because they aren't careful with chometz and therefore may have had chometz crumbs that came in contact with the food. If you're worried about that, perhaps you're also worried about a chometz crumbs that "contaminated" the fruits and vegetables before Pesach. Therefore you only eat fruits and vegetables you can peel

Comment: So you are bringing precedents on which this minhag is based, but not of anyone who has kept the minhag as is practiced now by chabad, et al.

Comment: @YDK: I'm bringing precedents to emphasize the point I made in the comments to the question. It is not a "Chabad custom". It is a much older stringency that many Lubavitcher Chassidim follow.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify:  There is an old widespread minhag to be careful of produce that has a chashash of a chametz contact.  Additionally, many are strict to include all produce without peels as these also have a chashash, though not as great as the chashashos mentioned in the Chaye Adam and Orchos Chaim L.

Answer (score 4):

I know of Satmar, Bobov, Belz who also only eat peeled fruit and vegetables on Pesach.

Comment: Do you have a source? I am curious why other groups do it. I heard that in Lubavitch they put their vegetables in flour during storage. I have no source for this other than word of mouth.

Comment: The source is family members that I know who do so and are part of these Chassidic groups. Your question was "Do other groups follow this Chumra" not "What is the reason of this Chumra".

Comment: @mochinrechavim: The Ramah (Shulchan Aruch 467:8) brings that we don't eat Safron or Tziporen on Pesach. The Darchei Moshe (Ramah's commentary on the Tur) - brought in the Mishna Berura (SK 33) and the Shulchan Aruch HaRav 467:21 - explains that this is because they use flour and yeast while processing it). Here's a link to the Mishna Berura: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&pgnum=141

Answer (score 3):

In Breslev we wash fruits and vegetables thoroughly.  If one is concerned about chometz in the coating, they consult their Rov.  Speaking for myself, it's not something I concern myself with.

Answer (score 0):

see teshuvos v'hanhogos 2:225. Also concerning wax, etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Could you [edit] this answer to add a summary of what it says?  As it is this sounds more like a comment than an answer.  Thanks and I look forward to seeing you around.