# Not eating peels of fruit

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, eating, fruits

What is the source for people who always remove the peels of fruits before eating the fruit. I've seen some ultra-Orthodox Jews do this and I was told by one of them that it is not a kashrut issue due to chemicals on the peels but based on some idea (kabbalistic?) of avoiding klippot which can be spiritually dangerous. 
Does this tradition differentiate between different types of fruits/peels and why?

Comment: Following this rule for all fruit sounds difficult, if not impractical. It is very difficult to peel grapes and cherries, for example. Would you know if these people are machmir regarding such fruits? Does this apply to fruits or to veggies as well?

Comment: I have never heard of such an issue. The only time I am aware of people peeling all fruits & vegetables is on Pesach. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15182/peeling-vegetables-on-pesach

Comment: I'd guess this is a misinterpretation of the term "klippot" as used in kabbalistic literature.